# What does a non-existing external function returns?

Tags: solidity, interfaces, royalties

I added a custom function, `customRoyaltyInfo`, to Openzeppelin's `IERC2981` interface. I need the means to check if a contract that implements this interface `IERC2981` support my custom function `customRoyaltyInfo`.

Consider the following

```
interface IERC2981 {
 
    function customRoyaltyInfo(uint256 tokenId, uint256 salePrice)
        external
        view
        returns (address[] memory receivers, uint256 royaltyAmount);

    function royaltyInfo(uint256 tokenId, uint256 salePrice)
        external
        view
        returns (address receiver, uint256 royaltyAmount);
}

contract ReadRoyalty {
    function getCustomRoyalty(IERC2981 addr, uint tokenId, uint price) {
        // What does `customRoyaltyInfo` return if it's not implemented?
        // And how can I handle it non-existence to prevent it from reverting the transaction ?

        (address[] memory receivers, uint256 royaltyAmount) = addr.customRoyaltyInfo(tokenId, price);
    }
}
```

I am aware of the `IERC165` `supportsInterface`, which I'm using to check for `IERC2981` support. However, I need to check if the function `customRoyaltyInfo` has been implemented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call a function that doesn't exist, the fallback() function gets executed instead, if it doesnt exist, the call reverts. If you're calling to a non-contract address, the call returns true but no return data (in your case since you're calling through an interface, it would revert too, because solidity adds a check to see if the address you're calling is a contract before making the call)

Comment: Thanks for the info. In my case, the address will be a contract and the code will exist. Would the call revert if the function does not exist?

Comment: Read  my answer again.

Comment: Thank you. I tested it, and it's precise, as you indicated.